# How to implement is_readable(file) in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, filereader, file-access

Normally just doing `FileReader.read...` and catapulting on errors would be the (async.) way.

But in some cases simply checking access synchronously before initiating the actual transfer may be better (see examples below).

- Can it be something like this *(in pseudocode; based on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14438187/javascript-filereader-parsing-long-file-in-chunks))*?
- Can it return true without actually reading the whole file?

  ```
  function is_readable(file) { // File object
      var ok = null

      function check(e) {
          ok = (SOME.ERROR.CONDITION.HERE ? false : true) // perhaps: e.target.result?
      }

      var blob = file.slice(0, 1) // does slice() make any sense here?
      var reader = new FileReader()

      // not sure which events to buy:
      reader.onload = check
      reader.onerror = check

      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob)

      // sync here for the result:
      while (ok === null) {
          alert('...waiting...')
      }

      return ok
  }
  ```

Example cases:

1. For batch upload (selecting files with a multi-file `INPUT`, and not sending them until an "Upload All" button is pressed), you want to list unreadable files in red. For this, in the list builder loop, you'd just select color for each `File` object `f` like `is_readable(f) ? 'green' : 'red'`.
2. Chrome(25) doesn't seem to set an error during `XMLHttpRequest.send()` here for some reason, happily posting the file, but *silently truncating* to 0 bytes, if the file is not readable. So I'd like to check it myself beforehand, as a workaround.

(Note: I checked [php.js](http://phpjs.org/categories/filesystem/) but it doesn't seem to have this one.)

Comment: Your question reads more like a riddle.  Can you reword please?

Comment: Why are you treating an asynchronous call as synchronous?

Comment: Because is_readable(), which I'd like to emulate, is a function call (which means synchronous by definition). The point of this checker function is providing a simple "instantaneous" query that is trivial to use, and can be cheaply called wherever you need it. It's purpose is to simplify the inherently more tedious and complex async procedure into something more like a trivial "propery getter". The sync. call requires nothing from the rest of your program, unlike async IO, which can't even be just a call, to begin with.

Comment: Have you ever heard of the [promise pattern](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/09/11/asynchronous-programming-in-javascript-with-promises.aspx)?