# UTF-16 byte array from file in javascript?

Tags: javascript, utf-16

I have a file that's encoded with UTF-16 and the encoded string has characters such as `à` and `÷`. The code I use to read the file is:

```js
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(real_file_button.files[0]);
  reader.onloadend = function (evt) {
      if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) {
         var arrayBuffer = evt.target.result,
             array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
         for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
             fileByteArray.push(array[i]);
          }
      }
  }
```

but since it is reading it as UTF-8 the `à` and `÷` characters get converted to `�`. How can I get a byte array of the file while keeping the correct encoding?

Comment: "*but since it is reading it as UTF-8*" - um, no? It is reading the file into a raw buffer of bytes, there are no strings and no encoding involved in the code you've shown. Where exactly do you output any characters?

Comment: Btw, what is `fileByteArray`, what's the point of copying the `array` you already have into it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing doing any conversion to UTF-8 here, you are just copying the numerical values from the TypedArray view to a normal Array (which seems quite pointless btw...).

Not sure what you call a "byte array", but if you want to read this binary data as an UTF-16 string, then use the [`readAsText( blob, encoding )`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsText) method of the FileReader:

```
const file = real_file_button.files[0];
reader.onload = (e) => doSomethingWith( reader.result );
reader.readAsText( file, "utf-16" )
```

This will default to little endian utf-16. If you need big endian, use `"utf-16be"`.

If you wish to view your ArrayBuffer as uint16 values, then create an Uint16Array view of it:

```
reader.readAsArrayBuffer( file );
reader.onload = (e) => {
  const uint16view = new Uint16Array( reader.result );
  // doSomethingWith( uint16view )
};
```